# jquery-ui datepicker : widget displays but no days of the month, no value created

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with the jquery-ui datepicker widget. I have a simple html file where the widget displays and functions properly.

But when I try to incorporate the widget into my project the widget displays, and does function but the days of the month are way at the bottom:

[image]

Here is a simple html mockup file that has the same problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>


<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jRate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/coffee-ratings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/coffee-form.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    
</script>


<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css"/> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.structure.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coffee.css"/>


<title>Create New Home Green Coffee Blend</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>date: </td><td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

since it works in the simple test file and not in the main project, it's not an OS thing. I've tried

- doing a diff on the jquery-ui code in the test area and the main eclipse javascript folder, they are the same
- adding and removing some of the different css files to see if that made a difference.
- downloading a new copy of jquery-ui, copied to both folders, still got same behavior
- The main app uses a new download of jquery, tried using the version that comes with jquery-ui was  the same.

has to be some kind of css conflict. I did not see anything that grabbed me in firebug.

### UPDATE

as I said in the comments, when I removed my main project css file, the datepicker rendered correctly. In playing around with my main css file, I was able to get the datepicker to display ok by commenting out the height in this block:

```
html, h1, div{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
```

}

but I need that in order to get the layout of the page to work.

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Well, while I understand you might not want to publish the url to the project I find it impossible to be able to help you with any debugging with what you've got for us to see.

Comment: @entiendoNull: good point, I created a complete html file that re-creates the problem that is inserted above, replacing what was there previously.

Comment: Compare the css of the test version and the version in your main project in firebug.  Determine which css is placing the control at the bottom of the page, and look for where that css is getting initialized.  You might need to walk up the element tree and look at the parents of the control.

Comment: Add complete sources to all your external javascript and css and we could easier have a look. Cheers.

Comment: when I removed the main project css file (coffee.css) the datepicker worked. Any way to point that element to the jquery-ui stylesheet?